# Class 'AlgoliaSearch\Version' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to add algolia search system into my laravel(5.6) web app. For this,

I followed below instructions

1. composer require laravel/scout
2. php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider"
3. use Searchable trait into my User model
4. use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
5. composer require algolia/algoliasearch-client-php
6. php artisan scout:import "App\User"

I also set (ALGOLIA_APP_ID) and (ALGOLIA_SECRET) both of my .env and scout.php file

I also added some dummy data to my users table and when I try to import those data to my algolia site by using (php artisan scout:import "App\User") this command I am getting this error (Class 'AlgoliaSearch\Version' not found)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Based on https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/install/ it looks like they use the version ^1.27 meanwhile you're using the version ^2.0 Could be the version ^2.0 not compatible with scout.

Comment: Please add code as text, not images. Have you tried running `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: I run composer dumpautoload but the same problem again

Comment: finally after changing the version it worked...Thanks cbaconnier

Answer (score 6):

I had the almost same problem

When I was doing the batch import using the command `php artisan scout:import`
got this Error:
**In EngineManager.php line 31:
Class 'AlgoliaSearch\Version' not found**

Downgrading the version fixed it

```
composer require algolia/algoliasearch-client-php:^1.27
```

Comment: Searched forever to find out how to install a downgraded version, thanks!!